# What is $\langle x_1 |\hat V(\hat x)| x_2 \rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions, matrix-elements

So I've become rusty in Quantum Mechanics.  What is $\langle  x_1 |V(\hat x)| x_2 \rangle$? Where $V$ is the potential and $|x \rangle$ is the postion eigenket?
$$ \langle  x_1 |\hat V(\hat x)| x_2 \rangle = ? $$

Is it with $V(x_1) \delta(x_1 -x_2)$ but since the position operator can also act on a bra is it $V(x_2) \delta(x_1 -x_2)$ or some combination of $x_1$, $x_2$ like $V(x_1,x_2) \delta(x_1 -x_2)$? If it does not make any difference can you prove so? ( I was doing a calculation where it seemed to make a difference).

Thanks

### Calculation where is matters

The following is a snippet of what I was doing.

Let the Hamiltonian $\hat H$ of the particle be:

\begin{equation}
    \hat H = \hat T + \hat V
\end{equation}

where $\hat T$ is the kinetic energy and $\hat V$ is the potential energy. Now, to find the velocity:

\begin{equation}
    \hat v = \frac{-i}{\hbar}[\hat H , \hat x] = \frac{-i}{\hbar} [ \hat T , \hat x] = \hat T'(\hat p)
\end{equation}

where $\hat T'(\hat p)$ is the velocity which is a function of momentum. Now, if we further assume $T'(p)$ is of degree $1$ and find the acceleration $\hat a$:

\begin{equation}
    \hat a = \frac{-i}{\hbar} [ \hat H ,  \hat T'(\hat p) ] =\frac{-i}{\hbar}  [\hat V,\hat T'( \hat p )] = \hat a (\hat x) 
\end{equation}

We know that acceleration must be a function of $\hat x$ since we have already assumed $T'(p)$ is of degree $1$ and find the acceleration $\hat a$.
Hence,

\begin{equation}
 [\hat a, \hat x] = 0    
\end{equation}

Now, multiplying $| x \rangle$ on the $\hat a$ equation:

\begin{equation}
  \langle x ' |  \hat a  | x \rangle =   \langle x ' | [\hat V,\hat T'( \hat p )]  | x \rangle
\end{equation}

Using the eigenvalue equation with eigenvalue $a$ (which represents the acceleration at a position $| x \rangle $ ):

\begin{equation}
     a  \langle x ' | x \rangle= a \delta( x' - x) = \frac{-i}{\hbar}  \langle x ' | (\hat V \hat T'( \hat p ) - \hat T'( \hat p ) \hat V)  | x \rangle = \frac{-i}{\hbar}  (V(x') - V(x)) \langle x' | \hat T'( \hat p ) | x \rangle
\end{equation}

Dividing both:

\begin{equation}
     \frac{i \hbar a}{(V(x') - V(x)) }  \delta( x' - x) = \langle x' | \hat T'( \hat p ) | x \rangle
\end{equation}

Let us consider $\langle x' | \hat T'( \hat p ) | \psi \rangle$:

\begin{equation}
    \langle x' | \hat T'( \hat p ) | \psi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \langle x' | \hat T'( \hat p ) | x \rangle \langle x| \psi \rangle dx = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{i \hbar a}{(V(x') - V(x)) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x)dx
\end{equation}

Or:

\begin{equation}
    \langle x' | \hat v | \psi \rangle = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{i \hbar a}{(V(x') - V(x)) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x) dx
\end{equation}

Due to the quantization condition of position and momentum:

\begin{equation}
        \frac{- i \hbar}{m }\frac{\partial }{ \partial x'} \psi (x') = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{ a i \hbar}{(V(x') - V(x)) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x) dx
\end{equation}

OR:

\begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial }{ \partial x'} \psi (x') = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{ - m a }{(V(x') - V(x)) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x) dx
\end{equation}

Let us now try $V(x) = - G \frac{m M}{x}$ (point particle potential):

\begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x') = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{- a}{(-\frac{GM}{x'} + \frac{GM}{x}) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x) dx
\end{equation}

Simplifying:

\begin{equation}
      GM  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x') = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{ a x x'}{(x' - x) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x) dx
\end{equation}

Again Taylor expanding around $\psi (x)$ around $x'$:

\begin{equation}
      GM  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x') = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{ a x x'}{(x' - x) }  \delta( x' - x) (\psi(x') + (x-x') \partial_{x'} \psi(x') + \dots) dx
\end{equation}

Plugging in the ansatz $a = - \frac{GM}{x x'}$ we get:

\begin{equation}
      GM  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x') = \int_{- \infty}^\infty - \frac{ GM}{(x' - x) }  \delta( x' - x) (\psi(x') + (x-x') \partial_{x'} \psi(x') + \dots) dx
\end{equation}

Note the term $\int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{ GM}{(x' - x) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x') $ goes to $0$ since is antisymmetric.

\begin{equation}
    GM  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x') =  GM  \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x')
\end{equation}

Hence, we get a consist solution which agrees with classical calculations.
Note: $a = - GM{x^{-2}}$ or $a = - GM{x'^{-2}}$ both will give wrong answers.

Comment: I'd be very interested to see a calculation where it makes a difference...

Comment: @Philip I've included the calculation.

Comment: @All Everything is correct except the last line's claim which states note: $a = - GM{x^{-2}}$ or $a = - GM{x'^{-2}}$ both will give wrong answers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of it in the sense of distributions, and then Philip's answer applies, in the sense that, as distributions

$$ f(x)\delta(x-y)=f(y)\delta(x-y)$$

but more intuitively, you can also think of $\delta(x-y)$ as having support only on $x=y$ meaning that it is equal to $0$ for all $x\neq  y$ (this is not mathematically rigorous, but it works on an intuitive level), so the only point where $V(x_1)\delta(x_1-x_2)$ does not vanish is $x_1=x_2$, so you can put either of them in the potential. In fact you can think of

$$ V(x_1)\delta(x_1-x_2)=V(x_2)\delta(x_1-x_2)$$

as the continuous equivalent of

$$ \delta_{ij} V_j=\delta_{ij}V_i$$

where $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise and $V$ is a vector. It doesn't matter whether you take $V_i$ or $V_j$, since in all cases where the above expression is not $0=0$, $i=j$.

Comment: The why doesn't that apply to the section: "Calculation where is matters"? Can you include that in your answer as well?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous sorry, I'm not sure I'm following the calculation, where does the ansatz of $a$ come from? How do you get $a$ from $V$?

Comment: The ansatz came from first trying $a = G\frac{m}{x_1 ^2}$ and then $a = G\frac{m}{x_2 ^2}$ both the equations give inconsistent answers but it must agree with classical calculations ... Basically you want something of the sort $a \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} = \frac{V'(x)}{m} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Let us experiment with the potential $V = -mgx$ (flat earth potential): $
        \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x') = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{- a}{(-gx' + gx) }  \delta( x' - x) \psi(x) dx $
Taylor expanding $\psi(x)$ around $x'$ and simplifying $
        \frac{\partial }{ \partial x '} \psi (x') =\frac{a}{g} \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{1}{( x - x') }  \delta( x' - x)( \psi(x') + (x -x') \partial_{x'} \psi(x') + \dots) dx$

Comment: Hence, cancelling the wave-function:  
$
a=g
$

The idea is to make the quantum case also abide with classical calculations of the calculated acceleration would be.

Comment: So you are taking the classical acceleration under the potential $V$ and "quantizing" it making $x$ an operator?

Comment: I think you might be right and that's what I might be doing in a roundabout manner ....

Comment: @MoreAnonymous I haven't had time to look at the calculation more in detail, but I don't think you should accept my answer, as I didn't really solve your problem as far as I understand. If you did solve it, it would be interesting if you included the details in an edit!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very good at the rigorous math, but the way I think about it is that "functions" like the Dirac Delta are actually *distributions*, meaning that they only make sense inside of an integral of the form:

$$\int_{a}^b \text{d}x\,\,f(x)\delta(x),$$

where $f(x)$ is a well-behaved (smooth, with a compact support over the interval, etc.) **test function**.

The quantity that you are talking about is *also* a distribution (it's just the product of the delta-function with the potential) and so it too must be defined in a similar way. However, it's pretty easy to show that:

$$\int_{a}^b \text{d}x_1\,\,f(x_1) V(x_1)\delta(x_1 -x_2) = \int_{a}^b\text{d}x_2\,\, f(x_2) V(x_2)\delta(x_1-x_2),$$

using a simple substitution of variables. As a result, both your answers are essentially equal, in the sense that their distributions are equal.

As to your example, there are many assumptions there that might be justified, but which I don't quite understand. However, there are some steps that I am uncomfortable with: for example, consider the step where you divide by $V(x')-V(x)$. The term on the left hand side is proportional to: $$\frac{\delta(x'-x)}{V(x')-V(x)},$$ and I suspect there are many problems with this. For starters, you will be dividing by zero when $V(x')=V(x)$, and more importantly, you cannot multiply distributions by singular functions, as the result would not be a well defined distribution.

Comment: They do a similar derivation in Quantum Optics in Phase Space by Wolfgang P.Schleich page 38 section 2.1.2 ... I can share a screenshot (of the book) on chat if you like?

Comment: I've got the book somewhere, let me take a look. But it's possible that it's beyond my pay-grade! :)

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot on the chat just incase you don't find it ;)

Comment: Ok, I must admit that they do do exactly what I say *shouldn't* be done. In fact, they seem to claim that $$\frac{\delta(x-x')}{x-x'}= \delta'(x-x')$$ which I *really* have a problem with. Now that I think about it, I feel like I have answered another question on PSE about this exact section of this book, let me see if I can find it...

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answers, if $V(x)$ is function of a real variable, then $\hat{V}$ really means

$$
\hat{V} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} V(x) | x \rangle \langle x | \mathrm{d} x
$$

where $| x \rangle$ is the same position eigenket as your definition
$$
\hat{x} | x \rangle = x | x \rangle
$$

You can verify that
$$
\hat{V} |x \rangle = V(x) |x \rangle
$$

And so yes, the answer to your first question is
\begin{align}
\langle x_1 | \hat{V} |x_2 \rangle = V(x_2) \langle x_1 |x_2 \rangle &= V(x_2) \delta(x_2 - x_1) \\
&= V(x_1) \delta(x_2 - x_1)
\end{align}